# jQuery Slider not showing dynamic images in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui-slider

I wanted to implement Lightbox Slider on my blade view. I just read about **Amazing Slider** and it was properly working for the images but for absolute paths. Now I want to let slider show dynamic images from my database. I explode the images into array and pass it to the slider. The slider doesn't shows any image and there is no any error on console.

However, when I click in middle of slider, it opens the lightbox and shows the first image only.
Please see the screenshot

[image]

How would I render my images coming from database?

Blade

```
@php
    $images = explode (",", $row->gallery);
@endphp


@foreach($images as $key => $val)

<div class="amazingslider-wrapper" id="amazingslider-wrapper-1">
        <div class="amazingslider" id="amazingslider-1">
           <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
             <li>
               <a href="{{URL::asset('src/uploads/' . $val)}}" class="html5lightbox"/>
                  <img src="{{URL::asset('src/uploads/' . $val)}}" alt="1"  title="1" />
               </a>

             </li>
          </ul>
          
          <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
                <li>
                <img src="{{ URL::asset('src/uploads/' . $val) }}" alt="1" title="1" />
                </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: please add increment inside div-id

Comment: @AlzafanChristian
Where to add ?

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Did you see that my image is not showing in slider but onclick it appears into lightbox.

Comment: no i dont but here inside div id="amazingslider-wrapper-1" will pointing to this div id="amazingslider-1", u didnt add increments, so all the ids are the same and pointing to the first element

Comment: @AlzafanChristian
I understand your point but don't know what to do next :(

Comment: it that still not showed up, check data, then inspect the image element, check if src attribute pointing to the right source of the file

Comment: @AlzafanChristian
Yeah image is there and path is correct, It's simply not showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220885/discussion-between-alzafan-christian-and-shaan).